# Multi-country and multi-language website in Drupal 8

Tags: internationalization, multilingual, drupal-8, country

I’m trying to create a Drupal 8 website with multi-country selection and more languages available for each Country.
For example, the visitor can select Belgium as his Country, then he should be able to select one of the languages related to Belgium: French and German, plus English (which should be available for all Countries).
I’ve installed two modules: [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) and [Country Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/country_path).
Domain Access allow me to define different domains and sub-domains like fr.domain.com, it.domain.com, etc.
Using Country Path I should be able to create **different path for the same domain based on Country selection**, like domain.com/france, domain.com/italy etc. But unfortunately it’s not working properly…
Using sub-domains is not possible for my project and, even configuring Country Path, if I go to domain.com/france I always get a page not found error.

What I need in the end is this path/url structure: **domain/country/language**, like for example *domain.com/belgium/fr* or *domain.com/belgium/en*.
Do you had any experience with this situation? Any idea or suggestion about modules to try or core configurations that can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module.

It will provide you with content translation,different path for the same domain based on Country selection and language switcher block.

[default looking language switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zBAG.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply David! This module would be very useful, but unfortunately it seems to be only for D7.

Comment: "This module has been included with Drupal 8 core. "